# 'halt' (Plug.Conn.halt/1) does not stop the call chain after a redirect in controller

Tags: redirect, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a "halt/1" in a controller based on some logic but not in a plug. Sadly, it does redirect, but also runs the code after the redirect.

```
if true do
  conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "Sorry, entered wrong")
    |> redirect(to: route_path(conn, :show, model))
    |> halt #this does not work :(
else
   _ #something
end

update_another_model() #this is executed
render(conn, "abc.html", model: model) #even this is executed
```

I actually need the call to terminate after the redirect, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `return` in Elixir - you cannot exit from a function early. If you need that, then refactor your `if` in such a way that all the statements that need not be executed are in the `else` branch.

```
if condtition() do
  conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "Sorry, entered wrong")
    |> redirect(to: route_path(conn, :show, model))
else
  update_another_model()
  render(conn, "abc.html", model: model)
end
```

If `condition()` is `true` the first branch executes and the result of `redirect` is returned (a response indicating a redirect). If it's `false` then the second branch returns the result of `render`.

Also note that if there is anything after the `if` then it will be executed regardless of which branch is taken and the result of that thing will be returned from the action - probably not what you want.

Comment: sad :( there is no `return`

Answer (score 3):

There is no halt/0. You are actually calling `Plug.Conn.halt/1` (note that you are using the pipe operator (`|>`) to pass in the variable `conn` that i assume matches `%Plug.Conn{}`).

[`Plug.Conn.halt/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#halt/1) will only stop plugs following your current plug from executing (remember that ultimately controller methods are also just plugs, and that plugs are always composable).

You should refactor this so that all action you want to happen if the statement doesn't hold are in the else block.

Comment: Thanks, altered the question to halt/1